# Adding python-pillow to buildroot

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling, buildroot

I am trying to add python-pillow package to buildroot. I basically want the package  to be present in my arm board (AM3352). I created the python-pillow.mk and Config.in files and sourced the Config.in correctly. When I execute make I am getting some errors and build fails. The errors shown are given below:

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '/lib64'
>
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
>
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '/usr/local/lib'
>
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: WARNING: unsafe header/library path used in cross-compilation: '/usr/lib'
>
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory
>
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory
>
> error: command '/home/user/HealthCubed/eclipse-workspace/Calixto/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> make[1]: *** [/home/user/HealthCubed/eclipse-workspace/Calixto/buildroot/output/build/python-pillow-3.0.0/.stamp_built] Error 1
>   make: *** [_all] Error 2

Any idea how to solve the error. I am a novice in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstream Buildroot already has a python-pillow package since the 2016.08 release, please update your buildroot tree:

https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/python-pillow

Comment: Thanks Peter. But the version given in buildroot is 4.2 which is not supported in my system. I was able to add 2.7 version with some tweaking and it is working now.